# How can I add more then two knobs into ion-range?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have made a timeline by ion-range, so user can choose time for whatever by moving knobs, and I need somehow disable some areas like it's already taken, so user could not choose time in that area.

I've been trying this by ion-range, but there's only two knobs and no options to configure it. If you have any suggestions how to make it work in that way, I'd be very appreciated, may be you know other way to do this, not by ion-range, it would be great if compatible with ionic 5

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqL43.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can't add more than 2.